# TransientObjectException in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

After sending a POST

> curl localhost:8888/bills/addbill -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"number":"111A111", "customer":"Customer Cuustomer Rrrr", "phone":"1 800 5551212", "manager":"Manager Manager Manager", "date":"2012-09-17", "curId":{"id":"1"}, "payments":[{"id":"1", "name":"pomyit stekla","price":"1000.0"}]}'

I get this:

> {"timestamp":1503954247880,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException","message":"org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: ru.test.practice.model.Payment; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: ru.test.practice.model.Payment","path":"/bills/addbill"}

I have a many to many relationship in my entity "Bill", here are the fields, that provoke the error.

Bill entity:

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="BILL_PAYMENTS",
        joinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="payments_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="bills_id", referencedColumnName="id")
)
private List<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<>(0);
```

Payment entity:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "payments", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Bill> bills = new ArrayList<>(0);
```

Here is my BillService file:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import ru.test.practice.dao.BillDao;
import ru.test.practice.model.Bill;
import ru.test.practice.service.BillService;
import ru.test.practice.view.BillView;
import ru.test.practice.model.Payment;
import ru.test.practice.view.PaymentsView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class BillServiceImpl implements BillService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BillServiceImpl.class);

    private final BillDao dao;

    @Autowired
    public BillServiceImpl(BillDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }


    public List<Payment> convertToPayment(List<PaymentsView> paymentsView){
        List<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<>();
        for(PaymentsView pv : paymentsView) {
            Payment payment = new Payment(pv.id, pv.name, pv.price);
            payments.add(payment);
        }
        return payments;
    }

    public List<PaymentsView> convertToPaymentView(List<Payment> payments){
        List<PaymentsView> paymentsView = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Payment p : payments){
            PaymentsView paymentView = new PaymentsView(p.getId(), p.getName(), p.getPrice());
            paymentsView.add(paymentView);
        }
        return paymentsView;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void add(BillView view) {
        List<Payment> payments = convertToPayment(view.payments);
        Bill bill = new Bill(view.id, view.number, view.customer, view.phone, view.manager, view.date, view.curId, payments);
        dao.save(bill);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<BillView> bills() {

        List<Bill> all = dao.all();

        Function<Bill, BillView> mapBill = b -> {

            BillView view = new BillView();

            view.id = b.getId();
            view.number = b.getNumber();
            view.customer = b.getCustomer();
            view.phone = b.getPhone();
            view.manager = b.getManager();
            view.date = b.getDate();
            view.curId = b.getCurId();
            view.payments = convertToPaymentView(b.getPayments());

            log.debug(view.toString());

            return view;
        };

        return all.stream()
                .map(mapBill)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Have no idea what is going on, I have already checked similar questions on stackoverflow and it doesn`t help. 
thanks c:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to persist an object which has relation to a transient object, your payments are not managed so when you try to save your bill you will get this exception.

**Solution1:** you need either to save each one of the payments and add the managed object ( the one returned from the save method) .

**Solution2:** you can just cascade the payments so when the bill is persisted the payments will be persisted as well

```
@ManyToMany( cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="BILL_PAYMENTS",
    joinColumns=
    @JoinColumn(name="payments_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=
    @JoinColumn(name="bills_id", referencedColumnName="id")
```